# OpenNI and OpenCV: cv2.imshow() crashes with error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.data == (uchar*)dst_ptr in function 'cvShowImage'

Tags: python, opencv, openni, orbbec

I am trying to receive a depth image from an Orbbec Astra Pro camera connected to a Windows 10 machine. I have therfor installed `opencv-python 4.0.0.21` and `primesense 2.2.0.30.post5` which seems to be latest stable python packages available.

This is the code snippet I am experimenting with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from primesense import openni2
from primesense import _openni2 as c_api

openni2.initialize("./OpenNI-Windows-x64-2.3/Redist")    

if openni2.is_initialized():
    print('openni2 ready')
else:
    print('openni2 not ready')

dev = openni2.Device.open_any()

depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
depth_stream.set_video_mode(c_api.OniVideoMode(pixelFormat = c_api.OniPixelFormat.ONI_PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM, resolutionX = 640, resolutionY = 480, fps = 30))
depth_stream.start()

while(True):
    frame = depth_stream.read_frame()
    frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint16()
    img = np.frombuffer(frame_data, dtype=np.uint16)
    img.shape = (1, 480, 640)
    img = np.concatenate((img, img, img), axis=0)
    img = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 2)
    img = np.swapaxes(img, 0, 1)

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(34)

depth_stream.stop()
openni2.unload()
```

However when `cv2.imshow()` is getting called I am receiving:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1230:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.data == (uchar*)dst_ptr in function
>   'cvShowImage'

I have no idea on how to convert an OpenNI frame to an OpenCV mat data structure and why `cv2.imshow()` refuses to show an image. OpenNI seems to correctly initialize, at least it prints `openni2 ready`... What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit**

This seems to be a bug which I have reported here https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/167

---

**Solution (kind of)**

Downgrading OpenCV version to the latest 3.x release made it work!

`pip install --upgrade opencv-python==3.4.5.20`

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of `img` right before the `cv2.imshow(...)`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. The shape of `img` is `{tuple} (480, 640, 3)` and dtype is `{dtype} uint16`

Comment: I have found the following which may seem related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13216

Comment: Looks like this is the case. I asked, because I tried in my machine (Ubuntu, OpenCV 4.0) with `np.uint16` and it worked. Maybe Windows build is messed up. Which version are you using? Maybe you should jump into this issue and report the bug if you cannot find the solution over there.

Comment: Thanks again. Opened up an issue, see my updated question

Comment: If I were you, I would see if the error happens when you try to run `cv2.imshow('test', np.ones((50, 50), dtype=np.uint16)); cv2.waitKey()`, because this probably has nothing to do with the `openni` and adding this requirement on the sample code only decreases the probability of someone testing your code.

Comment: Yields the same assertion error... so opnni can be ruled out.

Comment: I recommend you to update the sample code on the issue in order to simplify for those who might be willing to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
frame.get_buffer_as_uint32()
img = np.frombuffer(frame_data, dtype=np.uint32)
```

In opencv4 for some reason imshow will not work if you do not use specific dtype