# Laplacian and Sobel Functions in open cv are not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to run the Laplacian and Sobel Function to test the edge and gradients of the video streaming but while running the mentioned below code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(frame,cv2.CV_64F)
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('laplacian',laplacian)
    cv2.imshow('sobelx',sobelx)
    cv2.imshow('sobely',sobely)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I am facing the error using this problem, I though search from google also and trying to degrade the version of OpenCV 4 to OpenCV 3 and which is also not working on the laptop and facing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\test\CV\Edge Detection and Gradients.py", line 24, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('laplacian',laplacian)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1230: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.data == (uchar*)dst_ptr in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Any kind of useful advice on this will be a great help.

Comment: Your code is running fine on my machine. opencv_version : `3.4.4`

Comment: Which version did you downgrade into? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336237/openni-and-opencv-cv2-imshow-crashes-with-error-215assertion-failed-dst

Comment: Hi,I am using open cv: version 4.0